# Syntax Errors Regarding Amplitude

Tags: python, error-handling, syntax

Good afternoon,

I am currently seeking to compare the voltage amplitude versus time for measurements from an oscilloscope. I am running my code from a Linux terminal and I am currently experiencing the following errors:

```
    ValueError: Invalid number of FFT data points (0) specified.
    NameError: name 'yf' is not defined
```

My code is posted below:

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.fftpack import fft


sample_interval= -1
sample_num = -1
time = []
amplitude = []
with open('nofilter-1.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in readCSV:
        time.append(row[3]);
        amplitude.append(row[4]);
        if(row ==1):
            sample_interval = row[1]
        if(row ==2):
            sample_num = row[1]
# sample spacing
print("syntax")
yf = fft(amplitude)
xf = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0/(2.0*sample_interval), sample_num/2) 
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(xf, 2.0/sample_num * np.abs(yf[:sample_num//2]))
plt.show()
```

Am I running into any syntax errors or have a defined a variable improperly?

Comment: Can you post the full traceback please?

Comment: `ValueError`, `NameError`, and `SyntaxError` are all different things. That's why they have different names—and, of course, they include additional information in the description.

Comment: Anyway, if you're running this in an interactive terminal, rather than as a script, and you get a `ValueError` from the line `yf = fft(amplitude)`, then you haven't successfully stored anything in `yf`. So, if you go on to type in the rest of the lines anyway, you're going to get a `NameError` when you try to use `yf`. If that's your problem, forget about the `NameError`; you need to fix the `ValueError`, at which point the other one will go away.

Comment: If you read the error message, it says `Invalid number of FFT data points (0) specified.` So most like `amplitude` is empty—it has 0 points in it. You can try to `print(amplitude)` or `print(len(amplitude))` before the `fft` call to verify that. Since you're `append`ing onto that list for each row in the CSV file, that presumably means there are no rows. But you can test that as well, by adding, e.g, `print(row)` or `print('.', end='')` or whatever inside that loop. If it never happens, then that's the problem.

Comment: As a side note: `row` is a list of strings, so `row==1` is never going to be true. I'm not sure what you wanted to test there, but it's not that.

Comment: a sample from the csv could prove useful

Answer (score 0):

Sorry all for the late reply! Here's a snippet of the .csv file that I am working with.
[.csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjmKM.png)

As can be seen, columns one and three contain strings in some shape or form which is why I noticed in my code after having it pointed out that I may have mixed up the rows and columns. I followed the advice of bobrobbob and found very little luck.

Comment: this is not an answer. please edit your question. and my answer was very wrong indeed. sorry. in python lists are 0-indexed. substract one from every column number. ie `time.append(row[2])` it should work